# definition of level-preserving diffeomorphism

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, definitions

In *Hatcher, Allen; Lochak, Pierre; Schneps, Leila*, [**On the Teichmüller tower of mapping class groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2000.028), J. Reine Angew. Math. 521, 1-24 (2000). [ZBL0953.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0953.20030)) page 10 we have :

Up to **level-preserving diffeomorphism**,
there are five possible configurations for such a pair of saddles.

> what is definition of level-preserving diffeomorphism ?

Comment: Say you have a function $f : M \to N$, then a level-preserving diffeomorphism of $M$ would be a diffeomorphism $g : M \to M$ such that $f \circ g = f$.  i.e. it preserves the level-sets of $f$.  Presumably they have a similar context in their paper.

Comment: @RyanBudney .  how we can compare five configurations that is not level preserving diffeomorph ?  In the paper $f$ is a morse function; $ f: \Sigma \to I $  such that $\Sigma $ is a surface of type $(g,n)$ .I =[0,1]

Comment: Your comment is incomprehensible, you should edit the body of the question to make it clear what you are really interested in.